# Stop using app with certificate

Tags: ios, iphone

I create app with distribution build and custom UDID. Is there way to stop users of using it? Or when it will be stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the expiry date of your distribution certificate, that will give you the hard cut-off date when they will no longer be able to use it.

Unfortunately there is no way to revoke a certificate within a build, so you will have to wait until it expires to guarantee shut-off.

Comment: Even the question is so dumb, your answer(explanation) is valuable.